# How do you declare a generic type of an expression in a `requires` constraint?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I may be asking a wrong question here, but what exactly am I doing wrong that it causes the compiler to think that the constraint I'm expecting on pop method of the stack is `std::same_as<void, T>`?

```
#include <concepts>
#include <stack>

template <typename S, typename T>
concept generic_stack = requires(S s, T t) {
    s.push(t);
    { s.pop() } -> std::same_as<T>; // error seems to stem from here
};

template <typename T, generic_stack<T> S>
void compile_if_stack(S) {}

int main() {
    compile_if_stack<int>(std::stack<int>{});
}
```

I tried `std::same_as<decltype(s.pop()), T>;` and it appears to work, but what I don't understand is what's wrong with the former approach.

#### Full error

```
# clang 12.0.1
$ clang++ -std=c++20 main.cpp
main.cpp:14:5: error: no matching function for call to 'compile_if_stack'
    compile_if_stack<int>(std::stack<int>{});
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with T = int, S = std::stack<int>]
void compile_if_stack(S) {}
     ^
main.cpp:10:23: note: because 'generic_stack<std::stack<int>, int>' evaluated to false
template <typename T, generic_stack<T> S>
                      ^
main.cpp:7:25: note: because type constraint 'std::same_as<void, int>' was not satisfied:
    { s.pop() } -> std::same_as<T>; // error seems to stem from here
                        ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/concepts:63:19: note: because '__detail::__same_as<void, int>' evaluated to false
      = __detail::__same_as<_Tp, _Up> && __detail::__same_as<_Up, _Tp>;
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/concepts:57:27: note: because 'std::is_same_v<void, int>' evaluated to false
      concept __same_as = std::is_same_v<_Tp, _Up>;
                          ^
1 error generated.
```

C++ compiler from `GCC 11.1.0` comes up with semantically identical error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `stack.pop()` returns `void`, as per documented in [`std::stack::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop).

The constraint is not right, you should check for `top` instead:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
concept generic_stack = requires(S s, T t) {
    s.push(t);
    { s.top() } -> std::same_as<T const&>;
};
```

Comment: My bad, I just skimmed through `std::stack`. So the real problem is that my idea of the stack would be incompatible with STL, when I'm aware of this, the error does make sense... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack` does not return a value on `pop`. It has a separate function for that. Namely, `top`. So `pop()` is a `void` function. Hence the error.